# Java Struts2 Context initialization failed

Tags: java, struts2

every technology superman:

when i deploy a war,just find some error,like this down,If you ever have the same problem,I hope you could help me to answer,thank you.

> Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 22
>   14:15:18 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>
> Loading XML bean definitions from file
>   [/usr/local/webapps/Xxxx/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml] Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from file
>   [/usr/local/webapps/Xxxx[enter image description
>   here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqGbI.png)/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqGbI.png)

Comment: please add your `struts.xml` too

Answer (score 0):

This is an spring initialization problem not struts.

You have defined the `struts.xml` as an spring bean definition xml file. This forced the spring to load `struts.xml` which is, of course, not a valid spring bean xml.

Check you `spring-application-context.xml`. It might happen that the `struts.xml` is loaded by mistake use of wild cards for example: `<import resource="classpath:*.xml" />`

Comment: eh,maby. But I didn't use ths Spring's config xml.I Just use spring as my a contrainer for struts2. you can  look a image. I upload just now.

Comment: Anway，thanks. this is error in my project,if i start the server again，some logs print the Console.

Comment: Ok, you have at least one `applicationContext.xml` which needs to be checked.

Comment: um,well.I check some config xml now,thank you,Alireza Fattahi.